# Vue wrapper example

Tags: vue.js

There are a good [examples of integrating vue with select2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html).

I have a question.

If we look at this part of the code:

```
mounted: function () {
    var vm = this
    $(this.$el)
      // init select2
      .select2({ data: this.options })
      .val(this.value)
      .trigger('change')
      // emit event on change.
      .on('change', function () {
        vm.$emit('input', this.value)
      })
  }
```

I don't understand, why when we change value of select2, this.value changes too.
I expected a record like:

```
 .on('change', function () {
    this.value = $(this.$el).val()
    vm.$emit('input', this.value)
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing my previous answer, I realized I missed something important: contexts.

On line 5 in the jsfiddle, there is this line:

`var vm = this`, why?

This is because later on, when doing `vm.$emit`, `this.$emit` will not work; the context has been changed.

```
  .on('change', function () {
      //this = select2 element

      vm.value // == 1
      this.value // == 2
      vm.$emit("input", this.value);

  })
```

The value on the emit event is not that of the component, but of the `select2` element.

While the `value` has not yet been changed on the component, the new value has been broadcasted to the parent.

Answer (score 2):

It behaves that way because of how `v-model` works. What you are a looking at is a 2-way binding. Where if the value of `selected` in `v-model="selected"` changes, the value will be pushed down to the component.

When `vm.$emit('input', this.value)` is called, it tells the parent to update whatever variable is listening to changes, in this case `selected`, which it turn gets pushed back to the component such that its value gets changed.

To make it simpler to understand, this is the sequence of events:

1. select2's value changes
2. the select2 value change triggers an event emission
3. the parent receives the event and updates `selected`
4. the component's value gets assigned to the new value of `selected`
5. the watcher for the value gets triggered and updates select2 with the new value

Good question though.

Caveat: Doing this is understandably poor practice. It will break it sad ways when used with 1-way bindings.

Comment: At first I thought it would be easy, but now I realise that this question got me thinking real hard. All this information doesn't connect in my head now. You seem to be understanding this better than me. Could you explain what exactly triggers the `selected` update (step 3)? So `input` event got emitted, what's next? There's not explicit reassignment here.

Comment: `:value="selected"` is the explicit assignment. It basically means "whenever `selected` changes, update the prop value" while the component is listening for the prop value to change.

Comment: This part is clear to me, the question is how `selected` gets changed in parent component in the first place? What points or let's say "connects"  `vm.$emit('input', this.value)` to the change of `selected` value in the parent component? I hope I understood you right and we aren't just going in circles.

Comment: Didn't you explain this in your own answer? The @input listener on the component calls `this.selected = newValue`.

Comment: Yes, I guess this is what I did. Reading you answer gave me an impression that I know nothing and don't understand the process at all for some reason. Thanks for you time Slava.

Comment: @oniondomes While trying to make a JSFiddle for you, I realized I missed something important. Going to post it as a separate answer.

Comment: Step 5 is not needed when we update the select value. But it still works))

Comment: It is needed for when you modify `selected` from outside of the component.

Comment: Да, но конкретно здесь этот шаг работает "в холостую". А так, конечно же.

Answer (score 1):

Notice how `select2` component used in the template:

```
<select2 :options="options" v-model="selected">
  <option disabled value="0">Select one</option>
</select2>
```

In Vue.js using `v-model` with components could be simplified to:

```
<your-component
    :value="selected"
    @input="value => { selected = value }">
</your-component>
```

So every time you emit an event from your component the value gets changed at the parent component.

[Source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-)